# Manually ordering the SelectList contents from DataBase in MVC .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My issue is that with an older system the List of Roles is garbled...
For Example

```
ApplicationUser     ID=1
MasterUser          ID=2
UserRepresentative  ID=3
Admin               ID=4
MasterAdmin         ID=5
User1               ID=6
User2               ID=7
User3               ID=8
```

While I need the list to be in the following order:

```
MasterAdmin        ID=5
Admin              ID=4
MasterUser         ID=2
User1              ID=6
User2              ID=7
User3              ID=8
ApplicationUser    ID=1
UserRepresentative ID=3
```

I can't figure out how to do this with C# in the controller, I know how to exclude what I don't need as it's pulled in, but don't know how to order it like this...

Ordinarily I'd just order the roles in the Database, but this being an older system with hundreds of users in various roles, that is not an option.

Comment: Without some sort of field to have the code sort on (e.g. using LINQ's .OrderBy() extension), you'll have to just manually put them in order. Are you able to add a SortOrder field into the database table?

Comment: That is what me and my supervisor just discussed, likely what will happen. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to add another column to your  table and use that to do the sort. Assuming your table has a column called "`DisplayOrder`", you may simply do this

```
db.Roles.OrderBy(s=>s.DisplayOrder)
```

If you cannot add this column to the db table, you can do something like this.  Specify(Hard code) the order in a list variable and use that for order by

```
var displayOrder = new List<string> { "MasterAdmin", "Admin", "MasterUser" ,
                                              "User1","User2","User3","ApplicationUser"};
```

Now you can use this list for your order by

```
var result=  db.Roles.OrderBy(s=>displayOrder.IndexOf(s.RoleName)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'Rank' column to the table so that it now reads:

```
MasterAdmin ID=5 Rank=1
Admin       ID=4 Rank=2
etc.
```